# Touch events after moving a few units

Tags: android, motionevent

I'm trying to make a touch event that won't be activated until the finger has moved a few units from the initial position.

So far I've set up my onTouch method like this:

```
private XYEvents xyEvent =  new XYEvents();

public boolean motionTracker(MotionEvent event, int n)
{
    int note = n;   

    switch(event.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xyEvent.setInitial(event);
            playNote(note);

        break; 


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        byte data1;
        byte data2;

//I figured I should input a condition to check if the finger has moved a few units before it should start doing stuff like so:

            if (xyEvent.getXThreshold(event))
            {
                int xMod = xyEvent.eventActions(event)[0];

                data1 = (byte) (xMod & 0x7f);
                data2 = (byte) ((xMod & 0x7f00) >> 8);
                xModulation((int)data1, (int)data2); 
            }


        break;
     }
```

This method is the one I'm having problems with:

```
private float initialX, initialY;
private int xValue; 

boolean getXThreshold(MotionEvent event)
{
    float deltaX = event.getX();
    float threshold = 10;

    float condition = (deltaX - initialX);

    if(condition <= threshold || condition >= -threshold )
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

the getXThreshold method seems to do what it's supposed to in another method that looks like this:

```
public int[] eventActions(MotionEvent event)
{   
    int value = xValue;

    int xNull = 8192;


    if(!getXThreshold(event))
        xValue = xNull;


    if(getXThreshold(event))
        xValue = xHandleMove(event, true);


    return value;


}
```

Any suggestions?

/M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this argument:

```
if(condition <= threshold || condition >= -threshold )
    return false;
else 
    return true;
```

Needed to be flipped around, otherwise it always returned false for some reason.

Now it looks like this and works great.

```
boolean getXThreshold(MotionEvent event)
{
    float deltaX = event.getX();
    float threshold = 10;

    float condition = (deltaX - initialX);

    return condition >= threshold || condition <= -threshold;
}
```

Have a great week!
/M